# How do I span rows and columns with pe:sheet?

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, handsontable, primefaces-extensions

I'm trying to create an application where a user can edit excel cell content and wanted to use the [PrimeFaces Extensions `pe:sheet`](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/sheet/dynamicColumns.jsf). I am able to display the content in the cells pretty easily, however I'm not finding a solution to be able to merge cells.

Does anyone know of a way to merge rows and columns using this extension from PrimeFaces?

Answer (score 1):

I am the author.  The Sheet is based on HandsonTable.js which you can see the merged cell demo here:

https://docs.handsontable.com/4.0.0/demo-merged-cells.html

```
var
  container = document.getElementById('example1'),
  hot;

hot = new Handsontable(container, {
  data: Handsontable.helper.createSpreadsheetData(100, 18),
  colWidths: [47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47],
  rowHeaders: true,
  colHeaders: true,
  contextMenu: true,
  mergeCells: [
    {row: 1, col: 1, rowspan: 3, colspan: 3},
    {row: 3, col: 4, rowspan: 2, colspan: 2},
    {row: 5, col: 6, rowspan: 3, colspan: 3}
  ]
});
```

See our example here on using "extender" or "updateSettings" so you can set the Javascript for merged cells on load.

https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/sheet/dynamicColumns.jsf

```
<pe:sheet id="sheet" 
  value="#{sheetDynamicController.sheetRows}" 
  var="row" height="400" 
  rowKey="#{row.id}" 
  showRowHeaders="true" 
  sortBy="#{row.id}" 
  sortOrder="ascending"  
  width="800"  
  widgetVar="sheetWidget"  
  extender="sheetExtender">
```

...

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
function sheetExtender() {  
    this.cfg.mergeCells: [
        {row: 1, col: 1, rowspan: 3, colspan: 3},
        {row: 3, col: 4, rowspan: 2, colspan: 2},
        {row: 5, col: 6, rowspan: 3, colspan: 3}
      ];  
};
```

Comment: Thanks... I already upvoted before... up to the 3000 reputation ;-)